# stack linked - list C

Tags: linked-list, stack

So I was playing around with linked lists stacks and I cannot figure out how to output char instead of int. To my shame it's been some hours of only getting ASCII values(40 and 97 here). I could really use some light here as I feel i am missing something very basic. Thank you

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct STACKnode* link;
struct STACKnode { char item; link next; }; 
static link head;

link NEW(char item, link next) 
{ 
link x = malloc(sizeof *x);
x->item = item; 
x->next = next; 
return x; 
}

void STACKinit(int maxN) { head = NULL; }

int STACKempty() { return head == NULL; }

void STACKpush(char item) { head = NEW(item, head); }

char  STACKpop() 
{ 
char item = head->item;  
link t = head->next;
free(head); 
head = t; 
return item; 
}

void STACKprint()
{
  link temp=head; 
while(temp!=NULL)
{
    printf("%i\n",temp->item); 
    temp = temp->next;
}
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{ 
    STACKinit(10);
    STACKpush('a');
    STACKpush('(');
    STACKprint();   
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
printf("%i\n",temp->item);
```

You probably want this, instead:

```
printf("%c\n",temp->item);
```

`%i` is used to format its input as a decimal integer.  `%c` formats it as a character.

Comment: Thank you!! I have changed and changed the code so many times and I still can't believe I missed this. You have gave me some serious peace of mind.